# Why might some video not go through a USB hub?

Tags: usb, debugging, usb-hub

I'm having a strange problem with a USB Hub. I'm using a Microchip [USB7206](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/USB7206) evaluation kit.

I have two camera boards.

- The first is a [Leopard Imaging stereo camera board](https://www.leopardimaging.com/product/3d-stereo-cameras/li-ov580-ov7251st/), which uses an [OV00580](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/979877/OMNIVISION/OV00580-B21G-1C/608/1/OV00580-B21G-1C.html) image processor to join the frames from two [OV7251](https://www.ovt.com/sensors/OV7251) MIPI cameras into a single 1280x480 image, and stream the images over USB 3.0.
- The second board is my own design, using a [Lattice Crosslink FPGA](https://www.latticesemi.com/Products/FPGAandCPLD/CrossLink) to join the two images together, then a [Cypress CX3](https://www.cypress.com/products/ez-usb-cx3-programmable-mipi-csi-2-usb-30-camera-controller) chip to stream the resulting MIPI over USB 3.0.

Both stereo camera boards work fine when connected directly into the USB 3.0 socket on my PC's motherboard.

The Leopard imaging board works fine when connected to the PC through the USB7206 USB Hub.

However, my own CX3 based board does not work when connected through the USB7206 USB Hub. It is recognised by the PC, and configured correctly, and appears in Device Manager, but images are not received at the PC.

I have confirmed that my board is receiving enough power from the USB hub.

[image: CX3 based stereo camera not working through USB7206 USB 3.0 hub.]

Questions:

- Are there any reasons why a specific device might not work through a USB Hub, but would work when connected directly to the PC motherboard?
- How might I go about debugging this? Would there be any useful clues from a USB Analyzer / packet sniffer, E.G. [Free USB Analyzer](https://freeusbanalyzer.com/)?

***UPDATE:*** I have tried it on a different hub, this one based on the [GL3520](http://www.genesyslogic.com/en/product_view.php?show=26) chip. That one works fine, but sadly that chip is not available for purchase. I should mention that I am also working on my own triple stereo camera board, using three CX3 chips, and a USB7206. I'm trying to work out why my board doesn't seem to pass through any camera data, so I thought I'd go back to basics and test the CX3 with the USB7206 eval kit.

Comment: Actual cause aside, you probably can't do anything about it. No point trying to debug. I have this issue with my mice. Works through hub without drivers but does not work with proper drivers indtalled.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Thanks for the comment. Is that just pessimism, or is that known to be true?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Have you tried using a different USB hub? That would tell you whether the problem is on the hub side or the board side.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet More so just that even if you knew what the cause was, in which places could it be where you could actually do something about it? Not the hub hardware, not the PC side drivers. The only other thing I would attempt is a powered hub if your device is USB powered.

Comment: @AdamHaun - I've updated the question to say that I have tried it with a different hub, and it works through that.

Comment: do you see any R values on Hub to predefine ports.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - Port definitions are not the issue. As I explain in the question, the hub works fine with one stereo camera board, but not another. So I know that the port is configured correctly.

Comment: Get the onboard diagnostics info, that U weren't aware of , to debug your incompatibility from MIcrochip p29 to enable output on p96 or add diagnostics to yours, if that is insufficient.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - Are you referring to specific diagnostics that you are aware of? Is there some diagnostic apparatus or application that Microchip offer that I haven't been able to find? Pins 24 and 96 are not documented in the datasheet beyond "do not connect".

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVU6I.png  3 people down-voted my attempt to help you, so I deleted it , good luck [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Could you check the USB voltages, to see if it is a stable 5V?

Comment: @Ferrybig - I did already, and they are stable at 5v.

Comment: Do you have a scope capable of looking at USB 3.0 communications? Maybe the slight impedance mismatches in the dev board and in your board add up together into a signal that is too bad

Comment: Maybe perform USB packet captures of the Leopard / CX3 and compare their timings?  Perhaps yours is slow (or fast) in some way which causes problems with the 7206.

Comment: How long are your cables? Did you try a very short one?

Comment: What do you mean "recognized"? What exactly is recognized? Is the driver loaded? What do you see in USBTreeView https://superuser.com/a/1181052/620011 ?

Comment: Did you test your device/cable  with USB-IF command verifier, for basic "Chapter 9" functionality? https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb3cv Does it pass 150 enumerations at least?

Comment: @Ferrybig - Sadly, no scope that fast.

Comment: @Ale..chenski - I tried a very short cable, no improvement. When I say recognized I mean it correctly enumerates as a camera. It's name appears in the correct category in device manager, and Windows Camera allows me to switch to it. Windows Camera tries to show me the image, but nothing appears on screen.

Comment: Are you sure that your device gets connected at super-speed (USB3 5Gbps) rate, and not at USB2 HS? What USBTreeView says?

Comment: Have you tried zadig install ? http://zadig.akeo.ie ...

Comment: @Antonio51 - Thanks, but I'm not sure if that would address the problem, which is not a lack of drivers (since the devices work when connected directly to the PC), but some kind of incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

> How might I go about debugging this? Would there be any useful clues
> from a USB Analyzer / packet sniffer

It's been a while since I used [USBView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/usbview).

> "It is recognised by the PC, and configured correctly, and appears in
> Device Manager, but images are not received at the PC."

Along with that, since you have combinations of good & bad setups; You have a good chance to diff out what is more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [Monitoring Controls Active X library (paid)](https://www.hhdsoftware.com/usb-monitoring-control?utm_source=dms) to debug your connection state error.

> Functionalities

> USB Monitoring Control allows you to easily intercept, process and analyze data that is being transferred between any USB device and the host (computer) by your software application.

> Using our ActiveX library you'll easily get access to all USB requests which flows between USB host controller/USB hub and the USB hardware device during enumeration: USB Request Block (URB), IOCTL, IRP: PNP and Power I/O Request Packets. It intercepts all descriptors, interface & endpoint requests made by USB applications and shares access to captured USB bulk, interrupt, isochronous and control transfers. All these data is easily accessible by your application.

> USBMC offers "Layered parsing" technology for native interface allowing you to skip several parsing steps in order to optimize performance. Highly optimized algorithms allow non-intrusive monitoring on USB 2.0 Low Speed, Full Speed, Hi-Speed and USB 3.0 SuperSpeed and USB 3.x SuperSpeed+ data transfer rates.

> It provides you with open source sample applications written in Microsoft Visual C++, Microsoft Visual C#, Microsoft Visual Basic, JavaScript and Delphi.

Also compare device connections packets and statistics in USBView with the expanded version. (14 day trial)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

USB has limited Bandwidth with devices being added this will keep being consumed. If you are sending the data via another device this might reduce the bandwidth not giving you the video data. This might be one problem or the other might be diver issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure that bandwidth is not the problem. USB 3.0 should be good for several cameras, and it doesn't even work for one.

Comment: If I got it right (8bit RAW, 640x480, 100fps) = 147.46Mbps and USB 3.0 is 5Gbps

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.